# Mistake in shell function to count even numbers

Tags: bash, scripts, functions

For an assignment I have to write a function that prints the number of even numbers when provided with a sequence of numbers.

I used the piece of code I used for a previous assignment (to print `1` when a number was even and `0` when the number was odd)

My problem now is that my function keeps printing `0`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# File: nevens.sh

# Write a function called nevens which prints the number of even numbers when provided with a sequence of numbers.
# Check: input nevens 42 6 7 9 33 = output 2

function nevens {

        local sum=0

        for element in $@
        do
                let evencheck=$(( $# % 2 ))
                if [[ $evencheck -eq 0 ]]
                then
                        let sum=$sum+1
                fi
        done

        echo $sum
}
```

Comment: write in your shebang '#!/usr/bin/bash -x' then you'll see what exactly happens.

Comment: +1 for telling us it's homework - and for having worked on it hard enough to deserve help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[@dessert](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027699/158442) has found the core problem, I'll give some code review:

1. The shebang: There is no `/usr/bin/bash` in Ubuntu. It's `/bin/bash`.
2. It's good that you have declared `sum` `local`, and avoided polluting the variable namespace outside the function. Additionally, you can declare it an integer variable using the `-i` option:

   ```
   local -i sum=0
   ```
3. Always quote your variables (and parameters)! It's not necessary in this script, but a very good habit to get into:

   ```
   for element in "$@"
   do
   ```

   That said, you can omit the `in "$@"` here:

   ```
   for element
   do
   ```

   When `in <something>` is not given, the `for` loop implicitly loops over the arguments. This can avoid mistakes like forgetting the quotes.
4. There's no need to calculate and then check the result. You can directly do the calculation in the `if`:

   ```
   if (( (element % 2) == 0 ))
   then
       ((sum = sum + 1))
   fi
   ```

   `(( ... ))` is [the arithmetic context](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic). It's more useful than `[[ ... ]]` for performing arithmetic checks, and additionally you can omit the `$` before variables (which makes it easier to read, IMHO).
5. If you moved the even-checking part into a separate function, it might improve readability and reusability:

   ```
   function evencheck
   {
       return $(( $1 % 2 ))
   }
   function nevens
   {
       local -i sum=0
       for element
       do
           # `if` implicitly checks that the returned value/exit status is 0
           if evencheck "$element"
           then
               (( sum++ ))
           fi
       done
       echo "$sum"
   }
   ```

Comment: If you're looking for a terser loop body use `sum=$((sum + 1 - element % 2))`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Terser and less readable. ;-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I had the same thought that you should just use the mod-2 result directly.  (Or better, `&1` to check the low bit if that's more readable to you).   But we can make it more readable: `sum=$((sum + !(element&1) ))` to use a boolean inverse instead of `+1 - condition`.  Or just count the odd elements with `((odd += element&1))`, and at the end print with `echo $(($# - element))`, because `even = total - odd`.

Comment: Good work, and good to point out little things that beginners miss, e.g. `local -i` and `sum++`.

Answer (score 20):

You just forgot to replace `$#` with (`$`)`element` in the `for` loop:

```bsh
function nevens {
  local sum=0
  for element in $@; do
    let evencheck=$(( element % 2 ))
    if [[ $evencheck -eq 0 ]]; then
      let sum=sum+1
    fi
  done
  echo $sum
}
```

Now to test the function:

```bsh
$ nevens 42 6 7 9 33
2
$ nevens 42 6 7 9 33 22
3
$ nevens {1..10..2} # 1 to 10 step 2 → odd numbers only
0
$ nevens {2..10..2} # 2 to 10 step 2 → five even numbers
5
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you're open to other solutions.  Also I don't know if you can use external utilities, or if you're purely limited to bash builtins.  If you can use `grep`, for example, your function could be a whole lot simpler:

```bash
function nevens {
    printf "%s\n" "$@" | grep -c '[02468]$'
}
```

This puts each input integer on its own line, and then uses `grep` to count the lines that end in an even digit.

---

Update - @PeterCordes pointed out that we can even do this without grep - just pure bash, so long as the input list contains just well formed integers (with no decimal points):

```bash
function nevens{
    evens=( ${@/%*[13579]/} )
    echo "${#evens[@]}"
}
```

This works by creating a list called `evens` by filtering out all the odds, then returning the length of that list.

Comment: Interesting approach. Of course this will count ```3.0``` as an even number; the question wasn’t precise about what form the numbers would take.

Comment: @G-Man since bash doesn't support floating point arithmetic, it's safe to assume integers

Comment: Since the question mentions “even” (and, implicitly, “odd”) numbers, it is somewhat safe to assume that it’s talking about integers.  I don’t see how it’s valid to draw conclusions about the question from the capabilities and limitations of the tool that the user is expected to use.   Remember: the question says this is an assignment — I guess for school, because this is way too trivial to be from a job.  School teachers come up with some crazy things.

Comment: Bash can filter a list on its own if we can assume no elements contain whitespace: expand the arg list with odd numbers replaced with the empty string using `${/%/}` on the `@` array to require a match at the end of the string, inside an array initializer.  Print the count.  As a one-liner to define and run it: `foo(){ evens=( ${@/%*[13579]/} ); echo "${#evens[@]} even numbers"; printf "%s\n" "${evens[@]}"; };  foo 135 212 325 3 6 3 4 5 9 7 2 12310`.  Includes actually printing the list for debugging.  Prints `5 even numbers
212
6
4
2
12310` (on sep. lines)

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, I thought we could do something like that, but I couldn't quite get it right.  Very good - thanks!

Comment: Probably ZSH has something to properly filter a list, instead of depending on word splitting to rebuild a new array (I was a bit surprised bash didn't; only applying scalar string expansion stuff to every element).  For large lists, I wouldn't be surprised if `grep` was actually faster than `bash`.  Hmm, I wonder if there's a codegolf question where I could post that bash function :P